# Symfony: Get routing name from module / action

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

In `routing.yml`

```
Login:
  url:   /login
  param: { module: access, action: login }
```

then I have:

```
$module = 'access';
$action = 'login';
```

I want to get the routing name ?? // login

Something like `getRoutingName($module, $action)` return `"login"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is *almost* [`getRouteThatMatchesParameters`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/routing/sfPatternRouting.class.php#L482). It find a route for some parameters (module, action & query string).

Here is a quick snippet to retrieve a route name from a module & action name:

```
$routes = $this->getContext()->getRouting()->getRoutes();
foreach ($routes as $name => $route)
{
  if ($route->matchesParameters(array('module' => 'access', 'action' => 'login'), $this->getContext()))
  {
    var_export($name);
    break;
  }
}
```

Be careful. I put `break` because it can retrieve multiple route (for example it will often return the default route (which is generally `/:module/:action/*`)).

Answer (score -3):

`$currentRoute = $this->getContext()->getRouting()->getCurrentInternalUri(false);`

Comment: i don't want the current uri ... i want this $module and this $action

Comment: You can genearate the URL with [url_for()](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/UrlHelper#method_url_for). But i didn't heard about getting route *name*, it's generally not needed.